# Get last child ID's of sub categories

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have an category array of json data with the following structure.

My goal is when i pass the 'id' as route parameter,

- I should get the category matching the id.
- If the recieved category object has field `hasSubCategory=false`,then i should return the category document as response.
- But if the recieved category object has field `hasSubCategory=true`,I should again perform the db operation to query all the sub categories by checking if the object id matches `parentId` of the json array.In this case,if the sub categories again have `hasSubCategory=true`,another query is required to check the id of current obj with `parentId` of json array.When recieved subcategory also have `hasSubCategory=true`,another query is required.So it should query untill `hasSubCategory=false`.

Briefly,If the following object has `hasSubCategory=true`,I should check the entire json data whether object id matches any of the parentId.

In the above json,we can see that first object's _id is represented in other object's parentId .The _id of sub category can be used as parentId of any other object.Thus sub category may have subcategories which uses its id as parentId.

The categories may have deeper levels of subcategories and some donot.I am trying to make it dynamic.

**The End result what i am trying to get is all the category id's which donot have any further subcategories (`hasSubCategory=false`)**

Answer (score 1):

You've to work with an recursive function...

For exemple :

```
// Begin of your code
category = /* MongoDB Query for getting the category obj through id */

var myCategory = await findSubCat(category);
```

return myCategory;

```
// somewhere else you set this function
async findSubCat(category) {

    if(category.hasSubCategory == 'false')  {
            return category;
    }

    subCategory = /* MongoDB Query for getting the category obj through id */
    var children = [];

    for(i=0;i<subCategory.length;i++)
    {
            var mySubCat = subCategory[i];
            var myChildren = await findSubCat(mySubCat);
            children.push(myChildren);
    }

    category.children = children;

    return category;
 }
```

Comment: thanks..when i tried the recursive function above it returned an empty children array

Comment: What's your mogodb query ? A promise ? If yes, it's normal, else problem !

Comment: i am using async await  `category  = await mongodb.findOne({_id:new objectid (request.params.id)});`

Comment: Ok that not mentionned in your question, so it's crucial. You've to modify the recurse function, in order to manage it... (I make a try, but I don't have you code, but You should understand the process I hope)

Comment: It worked fine for the first category but since the recursive function keeps on replacing the `subCategory` in deeper level ,it works completely for one category with all its subcategories and the loop exits.So the next subcategories are ignored ..i could not retain the initial `subCategory[i]` after the first  category iteration is done

Comment: Heuh... How do you declare the subCategory variable ? 'const', 'let', 'var' ? If 'var', try to use 'let' instead .... else, Please provide, a full code with your db query, we can do with another way in mixing promise.all and recursive function...

Comment: sure can i share it here https://jsfiddle.net/Lt9u4h8v/1/ or any other way to share ?

Comment: I see in your code than subcategory isn't decalre as variale, can your declare it as `let subCategory = await...` and see what it's does ?

Comment: With let used ,the request 'Loading..' all the time..But without declaration it returns the first category with all levels of subcategories

Comment: In your code, where do you declare your subCategory variable, you certainly declare it somewhere, but i didn't see it before... that's the why i think.

Comment: I tried 'let' at the same place where i am getting value from the query and request hangs.When the variable is declared outside the recursive function it runs with one iteration

Comment: Yes that what I say, can you share you whole code, specially where subcategory is declared... that's the cause